# Set onClick value in React JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

I'm currently testing and I have a problem I can not solve. I basically want to change the onClick value from a div.btn before I click on it. The javascript code is in react.js and available [here](http://pastie.org/10283039). The part I like to change is here:

```
React.createElement("div", {className: "img"},
                            React.createElement("div", {className: "btn noShadow", onClick: this.sendVote.bind(this, this.props.data.candidate1.id)}, this.props.data.translations.vote),
                            React.createElement("img", {src: domain + this.props.data.candidate1.img_challenge_url, onClick: this.sendVote.bind(this, this.props.data.candidate1.id)})
                        ),
```

I am trying to set the value from div.btn.noShadow to "12345", normally I would just do the following in Tampermonkey:

```
$("#div.content > div.left > div.img > div.btn.noShadow").attr("onclick", "sendVote(12345)")
```

But this does not seem to work because react.js changes the DOM. I am fairly new to this and have no idea how to achieve this.

Comment: Have you tried passing the onClick down as a prop from parent to the child? In this way, the parent can control what the onClick should be.

Comment: No, because I _really_ don't have any idea how to do that :/

Comment: Well, when exactly do you need to change the onClick? You just said 'before clicking on div.btn', but that does not correspond to any event. If you have an actual event (onChange, etc), then in that event handler, you can change the onClick using setState.

Answer (score 1):

In React philosophy, you would want to trigger a re-render (which can be done by changing the state), and changing the markup based on the state/some condition.

```
getInitialState: function () {
    return {
        // ...
        fn: this.sendVote.bind(this, this.props.data.candidate1.id)
    };
},
render: function () {
    return (
        // ...
        React.createElement("whatever", {
            // ...
            onClick: this.state.fn
        });
    );
}
```

When you want to change the click callback:

```
this.setState({ fn: function blah() {} });
```

**edit: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amm9dvcj/1/)**

---

side note:

If the component has a parent, using props rather than state is better practice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I don't really see where I can set the value here. But as I said, I am totally new to this and I have no idea what I have to do exactly. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @Paranoia I added a JSFiddle example that will hopefully help. Also, what do you mean by "where I can set the value"? Are you referring to where you can set the new onClick function or something else?

Comment: Thank you for investing your time! I'll try to clarify: I am trying to change the onClick value of a div.btn that already has been rendered with a userscript. I don't have access to the page/script itself (well, I do, but we are testing if the competition we did has the possibility to cheat), the competition is here: http://goo.gl/ylyTgj (and no, I do not participate, just testing!).