# How to add click event with React createElement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Following is the code that I'm using to create an HTML tag. I want to add a click event on this. How can I add this?

```
let elem = React.createElement(
    this.props.tag,
    { 
        style: this.props.style,
        id: this.props.id
        onClick: ()
    },
    [this.props.text]
)
```

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31328784/set-onclick-value-in-react-js

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are creating an HTML tag, you simply need to pass on the onClick as a function to the element as props. With React.createElement you can write it like

```
let elem = React.createElement(
    this.props.tag,
    { 
        style: this.props.style,
        id: this.props.id
        onClick: () => {console.log('clicked')}
    },
    [this.props.text]
)
```

You could also pass a predefined function like below

```
let elem = React.createElement(
    this.props.tag,
    { 
        style: this.props.style,
        id: this.props.id
        onClick: this.handleClick.bind(this)
    },
    [this.props.text]
)
```