# How to create a link element dynamically and simulate click event react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying implement a function that takes url and navigates to the provided URL, from typescript function I am trying create a link object dynamically and simulate click event on  the dynamic link? I have following code to create the link element not sure hot simulate the click

```
const openExternalLink = (linkAddress) => {
    const linkElement = React.createElement('a', {href: linkAddress},linkAddress);

    linkElement.click(); <-- ERROR
};
```

The above code not compiling following is the error message:

```
Property 'click' does not exist on type 'DetailedReactHTMLElement<{ href: string; }, HTMLElement>'.ts(2339)
```

Any idea how to simulate the click on a dynamically created UI element?

Answer (score 0):

please refer below code sample

```
let elem = React.createElement(
    this.props.tag,
    { 
        style: this.props.style,
        id: this.props.id
        onClick: () => {console.log('clicked')}
    },
    [this.props.text]
)
```

You could also pass a predefined function like below

```
let elem = React.createElement(
    this.props.tag,
    { 
        style: this.props.style,
        id: this.props.id
        onClick: this.handleClick.bind(this)
    },
    [this.props.text]
)
```

**Credit :https://stackoverflow.com/a/55370859/13988407**

Comment: Thank you for sharing the code, the problem i am having is to simulate the "click" event. This will create element and binds the click event, how to simulate the click event after creating the element?